# Http request convertio api

Tags: https, pdftotext

Converting a PDF to txt using the convertio API and if after I send the post I send the get directly, the conversion hasn't finished and I get an error

I've worked myself out with a delay of 5 seconds but I don't know if it's the correct solution. The API provides a status call but it doesn't really say when the conversion has finished.